# What are the positive integer solutions to $x^2-x+1 = y^3$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, eisenstein-integers

The only solutions that I know of till now are $(x,y) = (1,1) \space , (19,7)$. We can note that:
$$x^2-x+1 = y^3 \implies (2x-1)^2 = 4y^3-3$$
Thus, if odd prime $p \mid y$, then $(2x-1)^2 \equiv -3 \pmod{p}$ and thus, $-3$ is a quadratic residue. This implies that $p \equiv 1 \pmod{6}$ .

How can we further proceed into this problem?

Note: As mentioned in one of the links in the comments, if we instead replace $x$ by $x+1$, we get $x^2+x+1 = y^3$. Thus, the solutions for this is $(x,y) = (0,1) \space, (18,7)$.

Comment: I think that the fact that $y^3\equiv 0,1\pmod{8}$ is useful here.

Comment: Yes, that is implicitly mentioned. $(2x-1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$ which shows that $4y^3 \equiv 4 \pmod{8}$. As $y^3 \equiv 0,1 \pmod{8}$, we have $y^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$. Thus, $y$ is odd. That is why I wrote 'odd' prime $p \mid y$. However, I am doubtful whether it can be used.

Comment: This is also an elliptic curve equation (in long Weierstrass form).

Comment: I've confirmed by computer search that there are no further solutions for $y \leq 160\, 000$.

Comment: Magma "says" they are the unique solutions.

Comment: http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/243/a/1

Comment: Wikipedia says that the form of elliptic curve is $y^2 = x^3+ax+b$. Could you help me understand how this would be an elliptic curve? This is of the form $y^3 = x^2+ax+b$.

Comment: Haran, the form $y^2 = x^3 + a x + b$ is the so-called Weierstrass (short) form, and any elliptic curve (over a field of character not $2$ or $3$) can be put into this form via a birational transformation. More generally, we can write an elliptic curve in Weierstrass long form, $Y^2 + A X Y + B Y = X^3 + C X^2 + D X + E$, and taking $X = y$, $Y = x$ and appropriate coefficients $A, \ldots, E$ recovers the given equation.

Comment: Also very close to being a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1214044/11619). Not voting to close because it seemed to me that the linked thread did not have a paper/pencil solution. Don't know if that's a tall order here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Theorem.** The diophantine equation
>   $$
> X^2+3=4Y^3
> $$
>   has only the solutions $(X,Y) = (\pm 1,1), (\pm 37,7)$.

**Proof.** From [this reference](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X84900532).

---

Adapting to this theorem, we rewrite as
$$
(2x-1)^2+3 = 4y^3
$$
Then the solutions are $(2x-1,y) = (\pm 1,1),(\pm 37,7)$. Therefore
$$
(x,y) \in \{(0,1),(1,1),(-18,7),(19,7)\}
$$

---

## **Algebraic Number Theory proof**

We shall use some Algebraic Number Theory to show that

> **Proposition.** Let $x,y$ be integers such that
>   $$x^2-x+1 = y^3$$
>   Then $x$ is a polynomial in $u,v$ such that
>   $$u^3+3u^2v-v^3=-1,\quad x = \frac{1}{2}(1 + u^3 - 3 u^2 v - 6 u v^2 - v^3)$$
>   or
>   $$u^3-3uv^2-v^3=-1,\quad x = \frac{1}{2}(1 - u^3 - 6 u^2 v - 3 u v^2 + v^3)$$

It is straightforward to see that solutions of equation 1 and 2 are bijective:
$$
(u,v) \longleftrightarrow (-v,-u)
$$
So the main difficulty lies in solving the first cubic [Thue equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_equation)
$$
u^3+3u^2v-v^3=-1
$$
In particular we know that there are only finitely many solutions and they are all below a certain bound: $|u|,|v| < B$. So a (smart) search suffices if we know $B$.

Unfortunately I was unable to find any elementary solutions, nor was I able to find a way to compute $B$ by pen and pencil.

**Remark:** This is a known Thue equation that is already solved in a few papers, say both in the reference paper earlier, or as in [here](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=cnkzxebjbycC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=but+Ljunggren+succeeded+in+applying+the+technique+to+deal+with+several+striking+examples.&source=bl&ots=GojmdZMJqq&sig=ACfU3U2lCyz45TdsdKTGo0MrmL8fWgFWyg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqt_6Gl5XgAhULuo8KHY5FCjEQ6AEwCXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=but%20Ljunggren%20succeeded%20in%20applying%20the%20technique%20to%20deal%20with%20several%20striking%20examples.&f=false). All the solutions look rather advanced/involved. More explicitly,

> **Theorem.** The only integer solutions to
>   $$
> x^3-3xy^2-y^3=1
> $$
>   are
>   $$
> (1,0), (0,-1), (-1,1), (1,-3), (-3,2), (2,1) 
> $$

---

We now derive the proposition.

**Proof.** Let $K$ be the number field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$. Letting $w=(1+\sqrt{-3})/2$, the ring of integers is $\mathcal O_K = \mathbb Z[w]$ and the units are $U = \{\pm 1,\pm w,\pm w^2\}$. $K$ has class number $1$ and hence unique factorization.

Now we solve the problem in $\mathcal O_K$:
$$
(x-w)(x+w-1) = y^3
$$
Since
$$
(x+w-1)-(x-w) = 2w-1 = \sqrt{-3}
$$
and $\sqrt{-3}$ is prime (since it has prime norm $3$), either $x-w$ and $x+w-1$ are relatively prime or they share a common prime factor $\sqrt{-3}$.

For the latter case, since $\sqrt{-3}$ has norm $3$, we require norm $N(x-w)$ to be divisible by $3$. This gives
$$
N(x-w) = N(\frac{2x-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2})=\frac{(2x-1)^2+3}{4} \equiv 0\pmod 3
$$
so $(2x-1)\equiv 0\pmod 3$. From
$$
(2x-1)^2+3 = 4y^2,
$$
we get $y\equiv 0\pmod 3$. Now taking $\pmod 9$ we get a contradiction:
$$
(2x-1)^2+3 = 4y^2 \implies 3 \equiv 0 \pmod 9
$$
Therefore $x+w-1$ and $x-w$ are coprime.

---

Since $x-w$ and $x+w-1$ are relatively prime, we must have
$$
\begin{align}
x-w &= \mu (u+v w)^3\\
x+w-1 &= \mu^{-1} (s+tw)^3
\end{align}
$$
for some unit $\mu \in U$ and integers $u,v,s,t$. By absorbing the negative sign into the cube, we may assume $\mu\in\{1,w,w^2\}$.

If $\mu=1$, equation 1 becomes
$$
0 = \frac{1 + 3 u^2 v + 3 u v^2}{2} \sqrt{-3} + \frac{1 + 2 u^3 + 3 u^2 v - 3 u v^2 - 2 v^3 - 2 x}{2}
$$
This requires $1+3u^2v + 3uv^2=0$, which is not possible (check $\pmod 3$).

For the other two cases, $\mu = w$ and $\mu=w^2$, checking the coefficient of $\sqrt{-3}$ for $x-w=\mu(u+vw)^3$ gives us the two respective equations:
$$
\begin{align}
u^3 + 3 u^2 v - v^3 &= -1\\
u^3 - 3 u v^2 - v^3 &= -1
\end{align}
$$
This gives the first part of the proposition. Checking the coefficient of the constants will give the other part containing $x$.

$$\tag*{$\square$}$$

---

## **Computer solution of the Thue equations**

We can solve the first using the [online PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html) with command:

thue(thueinit(u^3 + 3*u^2 - 1,1),-1)

giving us the solutions
$$
(u,v) = (-3, 1), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 2), (2, -3)
$$
Then putting in back $u,v$ into $x-w=w(u+v w)^3$ we get
$$
x = -18,0,0,0,-18,-18
$$
corresponding to $(x,y) = (-18,7),(0,1)$.

For the other case, the command

thue(thueinit(u^3 + 3*u^2 - 1,1),-1)

gives solutions
$$
(u,v) = (-2, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 3), (0, 1), (1, -1), (3, -2)
$$
and solving $x-w=w^2(u+vw)^3$ gives
$$
x = 19,1,19,1,1,19
$$
corresponding to $(x,y) = (19,7), (1,1)$.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks for the solution.